# How to resolve __init__() taking 1 argument when 2 are given amid child classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, arguments

I'm using python 2.7 and I have created a Dog parent class and a Cat child class; I have 'broken' the Cat class into two parts, and these two parts are meant to be linked as one, but are throwing an error:

Any ideas on how to resolve this, and as to the logic of this passing of arguments here?:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 6
    def age_update(self, age_update):
        self.age+=age_update
        print("new age: " + str(self.age))
    def speak (self):
        print("My name is "+ self.name + "and I'm "+ str(self.age))

class Cat(Dog): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)
        self.lives=CatNature()

class CatNature(Cat): 
    def __init__(self, lives=9):
        self.lives=lives

    def show_lives(self): 
        print("This cat has " + str(self.lives) + " lives")


cat1 = Cat("Fuzz")
print ("Cat's name is " + cat1.name + " and " + str(cat1.age))

cat1.lives.show_lives()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Python_experiments/class.py", line 27, in <module>
    cat1 = Cat("Fuzz")
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: A cat is a dog?

Comment: ;-) Yes, I was hasty in naming the classes.  For the sake of this experiment, my thought was that both cat's and dog's could share the qualities of having a name and age... and got too distracted by the error to return to that issue - I'll study your solution - and respond with any other questions - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I find it a bit weird that you subclass a `Dog` into a `Cat`, but that being said, the **`__init__` method of `Cat` is missing the `name` parameter**:

```
class Cat(Dog): 
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)
        self.lives=CatNature()
```

This is important since you pass `name` to the `__init__` of the superclass.

Furthermore it is weird that `CatNature` subclasses from `Cat` since it is not an animal, and you do not call the super `__init__` function. You can not call the parent class's `__init__` method anyway, since otherwise you would get stuck in infinite recursion: every `CatNature` constructs a new `CatNature`, and this will go on until either we get a stack overflow, or the memory is exhausted.

A better modeling is probably:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 6
    def age_update(self, age_update):
        self.age+=age_update
        print("new age: " + str(self.age))
    def speak (self):
        print("My name is "+ self.name + "and I'm "+ str(self.age))

class Cat(Animal): 
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Cat, self).__init__(name)
        self.lives=CatNature()

class CatNature(object): 
    def __init__(self, lives=9):
        self.lives=lives

    def show_lives(self): 
        print("This cat has " + str(self.lives) + " lives")
```